# Can the Facebook Blackberry app be launched with parameters?

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I'm developing a blackberry app that needs to be linked to the Facebook application(not using the SDK, just launching the Facebook app), I can do this using:

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_facebook");
```

But my problem is that I need not just to open the app, but open it inside a specific profile, what I don't know is if the Facebook app accepts some parameters to achieve this so I could send them like this:

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_facebook?param1&param2");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it cannot, RIMs BlackBerry Facebook application doesn't currently have a parameter API that's available to 3rd party Apps.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that, think I will have to open the browser with the profile instead.